# What could cause an access violation from mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::FireTimers?

Tags: .net, windbg, threadpool, sos, mscorwks.dll

The following access violation is crashing my application every few days. What could be causing this?

```
(80c.f28): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
eax=d628f91d ebx=29d706e3 ecx=29d706e3 edx=0bd2feb8 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=79fd897a esp=0bd2feb8 ebp=0bd2ff34 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac pe cy
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023 es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010297
mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::FireTimers+0x8d:
79fd897a 8b3f            mov    edi,dword ptr [edi]  ds:0023:00000000=????????
```

Here is the stacktrace

```
0:011> kb
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0bd2ff34 79fd8a38 0bd2ff9c 79f7759b 2fb73db5 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::FireTimers+0x8d
0bd2ffa8 79fd88ef 00000003 0bd2ffec 7c80b713 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadFire+0x64
0bd2ffb4 7c80b713 0012eb4c 00000010 00000003 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadStart+0x57
0bd2ffec 00000000 79fd8897 0012eb4c 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37
```

Here is my version information

```
0:011> !EEVersion
2.0.50727.3053 retail
Server mode with 4 gc heaps
SOS Version: 2.0.50727.3625 retail build
```

Comment: impossible to say without a stack trace

Comment: First chance exceptions are exceptions that are handled.

Comment: @Sean: The exeption is handled. You should not worry about it, unless you can actually change recompile mscorwks.dll.

Comment: leppie, why do you think this exception is handled? This is not a first chance exception. I'm not able to recover (continue running the application) after this exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The c0000005 exception is generally a memory exception. You are trying to access memory that is either in the kernel space or you have no permission on the memory area. The information that you provide is unfortunately not sufficient to help any further. At least you should provide the stack trace, better the output of 'analyze -v'.

And looking at the last assembly instruction I can see it tries to copy data at address 0, so this exception is simply caused by trying to dereference adress 0.